# UIButton not getting focus in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have custom cells with different buttons created, the buttons are always calling their actions correctly but my problem is that if I click quickly on a button, it does not highlight but is calling its action like I said before. I need to click slowly for a few seconds (1-2 seconds) to see the highlighted state. I think it could be because first of all it's taking the focus of the scrollview of the tableview but I don't know how to fix this problem.

Please help!

Comment: check the `delaysContentTouches of` tableviews `scrollView`

Comment: Try to set `delaysContentTouches` of the tableview to `NO`

Comment: I tried it but nothing has changed :S

Answer (score 0):

Try this code : Make the cell selection type none

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) 
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            }

            // Configure the cell...

             cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            return cell;
        }
```